# update lookup field with apex class and trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, lookup, before-trigger, cpq

Really need help with this issue:  I am trying to populate field Version__c [Lookup(Product)] on QuotLine__c object, whenever New_Management_Version__c (checkbox field) on Product object is set to TRUE AND Product Family(another field on Product object) is SOFTWARE. 
But don't know why Version__c is not getting populated.
Also would like to mention here, QuoteLine child object of Product parent object.

Apex Class:

```
public without sharing class QuoteLineManager{
  public static void updateVersion(List<QuoteLine__c> lstQuoteLine){

    List<QuoteLine__c> softwareQlines = new List<QuoteLine__c>();
    List<QuoteLine__c> versionQlines = new List<QuoteLine__c>();

    for(QuoteLine__c ql:lstQuoteLine){
      if(ql.ProductFamily__c == 'Software'){
        softwareQlines.add(ql);
       }
       if(ql.ProductFamily__c == 'Version'){
         versionQlines.add(ql);
       }
    }

    for(QuoteLine__c softQl:softwareQlines){
      for(QuoteLine__c versQl:versionQlines){
        if(versQl.Parent_Product_Name__c == softQl.Parent_Product_Name__c){
           softQl.Version__c = versQl.SBQQ__Product__c;
        }
      }
    }        
  }
}
```

Apex Trigger:

```
trigger QuoteLineBeforeUpdate on QuoteLine__c (before update) {
  List<QuoteLine__c> listQuotelinesNewVersionManagementTrue = new List<QuoteLine__c>();

  // need to verify if the New Version Management is true :
  for (QuoteLine__c ql : Trigger.new) {
    if (ql.ProductFamily__c == 'Software' && ql.Product__r.New_Version_Management__c == true ){
     //if is true I put it in the list
       listQuotelinesNewVersionManagementTrue.add(ql);
     } 
  }
  if (!listQuotelinesNewVersionManagementTrue.isEmpty()){ 
    QuoteLineManager.updateVersion(listQuotelinesNewVersionManagementTrue);
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you didn't get clear picture of issue. Looking forward for positive feedback. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following line in trigger.

```
if (ql.ProductFamily__c == 'Software' && ql.Product__r.New_Version_Management__c == true )
```

Relationship field cannot be used to refer parent fields as we have not queried the particular field. 
In trigger.new context only the object of current sobject record is passed and not the data from parent record.
To verify, you can display the value using system.debug as below before executing if block, it must display null.

```
System.debug(ql.Product__r.New_Version_Management__c)
```

To get the actual value from the parent record you must fire an soql to get the value of that field.
Apex Trigger:

```
Map<Id, QuoteLine__c> productMap = new Map<Id, QuoteLine__c>([SELECT Id, Product__r.New_Version_Management__c FROM QuoteLine__c WHERE Id IN: Trigger.New]);

// need to verify if the New Version Management is true :
for (QuoteLine__c ql : Trigger.new) {
if (ql.ProductFamily__c == 'Software' && productMap.get(q1.Id).Product__r.New_Version_Management__c == true ){
    **// Add logic here**

 } 
}
```

In Apex Class, following code is never executed, as only the software records are filtered in trigger.

```
if(ql.ProductFamily__c == 'Version'){
     versionQlines.add(ql);
   }
for(QuoteLine__c softQl:softwareQlines){
  for(QuoteLine__c versQl:versionQlines){//**This always gets empty list and do not iterate anytime**
    if(versQl.Parent_Product_Name__c == softQl.Parent_Product_Name__c){
       softQl.Version__c = versQl.SBQQ__Product__c;
    }
  }
}
```

Another issue that I find in the code is that you re creating a new list and adding records into that list. 
Which might not update the record as the trigger context will update only the trigger.new list.
If you face this issue. You must pass trigger.new to you handler class and iterate the trigger.new to satisfy the condition. if satisfied only then update the values.

Comment: thank you so much for the detail explanation. I tried your code, along with that followed your suggestion for apex class and made a query for 'Version' and added to versionQlines list and it worked. Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

Your apex handler class never compare  As there is no "version" records are passing from trigger. Trigger is passing only software records and you are comparing them with version in apex class.